# 'Token not found' en una funcion de reseteo de contraseña en Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, jwt, nodemailer, auth, express.js

¡Hola a todos!

Soy desarrollador de software Junior y estoy dessarrollando actualmente una app auntenticadora. Pero en cuando a la parte de "olvidar contraseña" me devuelve muchos mensajes de errores que no soy capaz de deducir.

Este es el archivo env:

```
TOKEN_SECRET: T0K€N
RESET_PASSWORD_TOKEN: T0K€N
```

Modelo del usuario:

```
     ../models/user.js
     
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    
name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 1024
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    },
    subscribe: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },    
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        minlength: 4
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        minlength: 4,
        defaultValue: ""
    },        
    nonce: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        minlength: 4,
        defaultValue: ""
    },            
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

Este es el modelo que corresponde al token:

 

../models/token.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6
    },
    id_user:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 1
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('expired_tokens', Schema);
```

y finalmente el modelo del token

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

//models

const User = require('../models/user');
const expired_token = require('../models/expired_token');

//nodemailer

const sendMail = require('../nodemailer');

ResetPassword: async (req, res) => {    
        
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            data: "",
            message: "User with this email doesn't exist",
            status: "error"
        })
    }   
        
     const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, email: user.email }, process.env.RESET_PASSWORD_TOKEN );

    const data = {
        from: 'noreply@hello.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Recuperacion de contraseña',
        template: "reset password",
        context: {
            url: 'http://localhost:3005/auth/reset_password?token=' + token,
            name: user.fullName.split('').split('')[0]
        }
    }

    const link = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/reset_password/${user._id}/${token.token} `;
    await sendEmail(user.email, "Password Reset", link);
},
//routes

router.route('/reset_password')
     .post(verifyToken, controller.ResetPassword);
```

Hasta aca todo bien, pero cuando lo pruebo en el postman, me devuelve con que no aparece el token que corresponde al reseteo de contraseña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que veo, la funcion no genero el token que le corresponde al usuario que esta reestableciendo su contraseña. Pero no tengo la experticia para deducir cual es la verdadera raiz del problema y como puedo llegar a su solucion. Por lo que de verdad agradeceria si alguien puede guiarme.

Gracias y que tenga buen dia!

Comment: `http://localhosy` -> `http://localhost`

Comment: Saludos! No, realmente me equivoque cuando estaba formulando la pregunta, pero en el directorio esta sin errores y aun me sigue apareciendo el mensaje de error 'token not found'

Comment: `url: 'http://localhost:3005/auth/reset_password?token=' + token,` Averigua por qué te da un string empty en la variable `token`.